# Hibernate update/delete one to many collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes `Parent` and `Child` with one to many relation.

Lets suppose that I have already persisted in my database structure like this:

```
Parent--> Child1, Child2
```

And than I get this new structure (with changes in `Child1`, without `Child2` and with new `Child3`):

```
Parent--> Child1, ​Child3
```

So: `Child1` should be updated, `Child2` should be removed and `Child3` should be added.

Unfortunately Hibernate with `CasadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval=true` only adds and updates, but don't delete automatically `Child2`. I need to compare list with entites to update and persisted one to look for objects to delete.

I wonder if there is any pattern that solves in elegant way my problem or maybe should I change some properties in Hibernate?

--- EDIT ---

Entities aren't anything fancy, something like this lets say:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Parent {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", casade = CasadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Child> childList;
}


@Entity
@Data
public class Child {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
   private long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "xxx")
   private Parent parent;

}
```

Comment: Did you set the reference from Child2 to Parent to null?

Comment: I know how to delete it. But I wonder if there is any pattern or build-in way to filter such objects.

Comment: Please show your entity classes

Comment: @SimonMartinelli there aren't anything fancy. I have just updated post. 
I just wonder how to change default Hibernate behavior or if there are any pattern designed to overcome this problem.

Comment: And you set  Parent parent = null when you remove the Child2 from the Set?

Comment: Please read carefully. I know how to delete it. But in order to find entity to delete i need to compare two list, find all children that are saved in database and aren't in new list, than take it and delete. I know how to do this. But I wonder if I can omit all this logic. I wonder if there is any built in mechanism in hibernate or standardized pattern to do this.

Comment: Probably the quickest way to omit this logic would be to delete all Child associated with given Parent and save all from new set. But it would create every time new entities and I would like to: create new ones (Child3 in example), update which should be updated (Child1) and delete old ones (Child2). Everything in one go.

Answer (score 2):

This is the pattern I follow:

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    public class Parent {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
       private long id;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", casade = CasadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
       private Set<Child> childList = new HashSet<>();
       
       public void addChild(Child child){

            if(child!=null){
              this.childList.add(child);
              child.setParent(this);   
            }
       }

       public void removeChild(Child child){

            if(child!=null){
              this.childList.remove(child);
              child.setParent(null);   
            }
       }

       public void updateChildren(Collection<Child> children){
           childList.forEach(x-> if(!children.contains(x)) this.removeChild(x); );
             
           children.forEach(x-> this.addChild(x));
       }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can create generic classes like this and use it. **NOTE: THIS IS WAY COMPLEX TO IMPLEMENT**

```
@MappedSuperClass
@Data
class Child<P extends Parent,C extends Child>{
        Parent<P,C> parent ;
}

@MappedSuperClass
@Data
class Parent<P extends Parent,C extends Child>{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", casade = CasadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<C> childList = new HashSet<>();

    public void addChild(C child){

        if(child!=null){
            this.childList.add(child);
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeChild(C child){

        if(child!=null){
            this.childList.remove(child);
            child.setParent(null);
        }
    }

    public void updateChildren(Collection<C> children){
        childList.forEach(x-> {if(!children.contains(x)) this.removeChild(x); });

        children.forEach(this::addChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quiet good answer. I guess that we should filter objects by its id, not all properties thus it won't work unless we will implement `equals` function to check only id's. I also wonder about more generic way. Maybe some library or annotation which generates code for us like Lombok?

Comment: For any object comparison, it is understood that equals and hashCode methods are overridden - unless somebody is new to Java. Since you need a more generic way, You can create a custom annotation to do this.

Comment: This def will run in to `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.